# Is there a way to check the conditions for using a BRIN index?

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning

BRIN indexes work best (or only) on tables where the data is banded together in physical storage.

Is there a way to check this beforehand, apart from testing or considering the logic that creates the data?

In my case, I suspect that my table is ordered on client ID, but I'm not sure if this is consistent enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% safe way to determine that, but you can look at the correlation in the statistics:

```
SELECT correlation
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'sometab' AND attname = 'somecol';
```

If that is 1 or -1 or very close to these values, a BRIN index might have a chance.  But remember that one far outlier per block range can already render the index useless.